# Can't boot from USB HDD on Samsung notebook

Tags: boot, usb, 14.10, samsung

So I bought a new laptop, it is a Samsung Ativ Book 2 and I want to install Ubuntu 14.10 on it. I currently have installed Ubuntu 14.04, which I installed form a CD. I have no more CDs and on my older computer I always installed new distros from a USB stick.

On this new computer, however, I can't seem to be able to boot from the USB. I've tried disabling fast boot, secure boot and enabling USB-something on the BIOS. Even after these changes, the USB HDD won't appear on the boot priority menu, where it should be even if the USB wasn't bootable.

Can anyone tell me what I can do to be able to boot from the USB? I don't want to have to buy new DVDs every time something goes wrong with the computer.

Comment: Do you go into UEFI settings (BIOS) with the usb inserted?  Some machines will reset the boot order, removing non-present devices.

Comment: Yes, I go with the USB inserted, what should I do, then?

Comment: Did you hashcheck the downloaded iso before you put it on the media? Can you boot on other machines with the USB?  Describe exactly how you burned the iso and the partitions on the usb.  14.10 only has 9 month support,you'd be better off with 14.04 I think.

Comment: This user said if UEFI fast boot on that USB ports not seen. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2203824

Comment: Do you choice between CMOS , UEFI or both on setup . I spent a long time to know how to recognize my internal HDD/SSD choosing just CMOS on setup motherboard

Comment: @LucasZanella - it is not clear here as thread : It could be that usb-plug of your usb-external device is newer than the usb-port of your machine (notebook). It is not clear - if you have dual-boot with Windows 10 ? It might be that Windows 10 has switched off the usb-ports ? Then Ubuntu boots with the settings of Windows 10 ?

Comment: Look if there is a newer BIOS available that might support booting from USB.

Answer (score 0):

In modern laptops, you should press F12 to show the boot-menu, where you can select USB as an option to boot from.
As I remember,the bios does not recognize it as an HDD, but a USB

Don't forget to use FAT32 system in your USB stick and install ubuntu 14.10 using a tool like unetbootin, so as it become bootable.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered several laptops which were anywhere from impossible to next to impossible to boot from USB, which given my hobby has been most inconvenient.  Certain laptops, such as my ASUS netbook can only be booted by pressing the escape key at boot time which results in "boot menu".  Please see if yours offers such a "Press [key] for boot options" alert at boot time.

**UPDATE:**
After seeing your comment I did [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Samsung%20Ativ%20Book%202&oq=Samsung%20Ativ%20Book%202&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=ubuntu%20on%20Samsung%20Ativ%20Book%202) to try to determine if this was one of those "impossible" situations I described, and it is starting to look that way. I'm not saying it is impossible, but I will say that if you have access to an asus, acer, gateway, HP, Dell, or Lenovo model ANYTHING, you might find your time invested better trying to make Ubuntu work with any of those.

Since your post indicates you purchased this laptop NEW, it may not be too late to return it.  If your goal is to use Ubuntu, this doesn't look like the best choice.  I'm not the fan of modern Dell laptops I was when their designs were entirely different (I still like older Dells a lot and you can sometimes buy them under $100).

Remember, although it is true that Ubuntu will always benefit from more ram and a faster cpu, its vastly greater efficiency means that to afford the same degree of performance, you could justify buying HALF the machine you'd need if you insisted on using Windows.  When you consider the price difference between any modern computer and your choices buying a quality used one either online or from some local computer repair shop that sometimes offers good used laptops at bargain prices, you really might appreciate the values you find that way.  Please also note that a lot of techs know about Ubuntu and local shops might help you to find your ideal ubuntu laptop.  Or if they aren't Ubuntu savvy, they may even appreciate your interest and knowledge.

Comment: It actually does, but on the boot options, I can only choose between HD, CD or BIOS. No USB...